# Get OS Type of an VM Image in azure RM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-stack

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage) we can get the offer , publisher and Sku in **AzureRM Cloud** .

Now How to get the Image's OS type(Windows or Linux) using any of the API in azure ? Because using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage#find-specific-images) I can be only able to get the  Publisher , offer and sku details , Can't get the OS type .

**My Question is how to get the OS type for any images programmatically?**

Comment: I got it ! But I need it in Azure Cloud !https://adminmanagement.local.azurestack.external/subscriptions/<subsID>/providers/Microsoft.Compute.Admin/locations/local/artifactTypes/platformImage?api-version=2015-12-01-preview

Comment: azure stack has virtually the same api, so just query it like you would with Azure

Comment: @4c74356b41 I got the Answer for Azure Stack , I have updated the question . I need it in Azure RM ,. I have Sku, publisher ,offer and also version . can I get the OsType of the platform image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Azure CLi 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to get OS type.

Using [`az vm image show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_image_show), for example:

```
latest=$(az vm image list -p OpenLogic -s 7.3 --all --query     "[?offer=='CentOS'].version" -o tsv | sort -u | tail -n 1)
az vm image show -l westus -f CentOS -p OpenLogic --s 7.3 --version ${latest}
```

It will return following result

```
{
  "additionalProperties": {},
  "dataDiskImages": [],
  "id": "/Subscriptions/*************/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus/Publishers/OpenLogic/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/CentOS/Skus/7.3/Versions/7.3.20170925",
  "location": "westus",
  "name": "7.3.20170925",
  "osDiskImage": {
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "operatingSystem": "Linux"
  },
  "plan": null,
  "tags": null
}
```

Note:`operatingSystem` is the OS type you want. The example works on bash shell.

If you use `az vm image show -l westus -f CentOS -p OpenLogic --s 7.3 --version ${latest} --debug`, you will find the API that could get the OS type.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westus/publishers/OpenLogic/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/CentOS/skus/7.3/versions/7.3.20170925?api-version=2017-12-01
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! You saved a hell of a time.

Comment: If you are one of the MSFT member I would like to suggest to add this to one of the documents. Because ppl with same need might get difficult to find it .

Comment: Any idea if you can run query on the JSON fields, e.g. osDiskImage.sizeInGb?